# How to Allow Form-Data in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, postman

I recently created an API that accepts files. I am trying to test the API using Postman. If I make a post request using `x-wwww-form-urlencoded` body type, everything works and I get all the expected data. The only problem is that it does not allow to send a file. If I use `form-data` body type, that allows you to send files, I don't receive anything at the back-end. Not sure if something is wrong with Postman or if I am doing something wrong. My hunch is that the back-end doesn't accept `form-data` currently, that is why I am not receiving any data. Anything I could do to change that?

My headers look something like this so far,

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, form-data");
```

---

**app.js**

```
app
    // static route will go to the client (angular app)
    .use(express.static('client'))

    // secured routes
    .use('/api', secured_route)

    // add a user route
    .post('/user', user_api_controller.add_user)

    // delete this in the production
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
        res = allowed_orgins(req, res);
        next();
    })
;

allowed_orgins = function (req, res){
    var allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:4200', 'http://localhost:8100'];
    var origin = req.headers.origin;
    if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, multipart/form-data");
    }
    return res;
}
```

**user_api_controller.js**

```
module.exports.add_user = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.username);
    console.log(req.body.other_parameters);
}
```

I get nothing print out on console if I use `form-data`, but it works fine when I use `x-wwww-form-urlencoded`.

---

I've used `multer middle ware`, I am still not getting anything. Middle ware comes into play when my back-end will receive something. I have tried getting the plain text fields of `form-data`, and I am not getting that either. That means my back-end is unable to receive all `form-data` fields, not just files but the text fields as well.

Comment: you need to pass req.body form The form-data @HafizTemuri

Comment: @muthukumar sorry I didn't catch that. Could you elaborate it for me, please?

Comment: your problem is not with the headers Kindly pass the multer Middle Ware

Comment: I used the `multer middle ware`, I am still not getting anything. Middle ware comes into play when my back-end will receive something. I have tried getting the plain text fields of `form-data`, and I am not getting that either. That means my back-end is unable to receive `form-data` fields, not just files but the text fields as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here my super simple express example:

```
const express = require('express')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

const app = express()
app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/file-upload', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body.msg);
  console.log(req.files);
  res.send('ok');
  next();
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Sorry I don't use postman, but I use `curl` and it works for me:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/file-upload \
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
  -F "file=@/YourDir/YourFile.txt" \
  -F "msg=MyFile"
```

So you can try it, test it, get the gist and play with your app using this curl command.

Comment: Using your solution, at least I am able to get text fields when I use `form-data` in Postman, which is a progress, I say. But, I am still unable to get the file. I tried using curl, and it's giving me an error, `Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" value of type "System.String" to type
"System.Collections.IDictionary"`. Any ideas how I can resolve it?

Comment: Can't reproduce this error... What other middlewares do you use?

Comment: I am not using any middlewares. I was using `multer`, but anymore.

Comment: Forget about curl...lol I got it working with Postman, but I got into another problem. I am unable to save the file to the server. I am trying to save the file as per this tutorial, and I am providing the path as shown. `https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload` Something like this, `/upload/filename.txt`, but for some reason its making up its own pathname. It suppose to look for a directory called `upload` in the root directory of the app, instead its going to my harddrive root. `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\uploads\filename.txt'` Any ideas how can I fix that?

Comment: I have got it all working. Thank you so much for all your help. You deserve my 50 rep.

Comment: P.S. It is saying that I have to wait another 50min to award the bounty. I have to do that later.

Comment: @HafizTemuri Really happy that you found solution!

Answer (score 2):

The Content-Type header for file upload is actually `multipart/form-data` not `form-data`. To upload a file appropriately in Postman please have a look here: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1441#issuecomment-289452571

In the backend, you would need a library to handle `multipart/form-data` request. If you're using expressjs then this library would fit your need https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Here is how to use the `multer` library

1) First install multer

```
npm install --save multer
```

2) Include the library in your code (note that the uploads directory must be existing)

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
```

3) Use `upload` as a middleware for your `add_user` endpoint (fill in the parentheses with your field name that contain uploaded file)

```
app
// other endpoints
.post('/user', upload.single(/* file field name in your form */), user_api_controller.add_user)
```

4) The file can be accessed in your **user_api_controller.js**

```
module.exports.add_user = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.file);
}
```

Comment: I have changed the header type to `multipart/form-data`. Still, it's not showing me any sign of receiving the data at the back-end. I have included more code in my original post. Please check if I am doing something wrong there.

Comment: To receive the file at the backend, you need to use another library `multer`. I've updated my answer to give some instructions.

Comment: still not getting anything. Although it creates the upload folder, but it does not upload the file. When I use `form-data`, not just the files, it does not get the text fields either.

Comment: Did you send on Postman `form-data` or `multipart/form-data`? and what is the error you got on the backend?

Comment: I sent through `form-data` and I am not getting any errors. When I try to print fields, it prints `undefined`

Comment: Try to send through `multipart/form-data`, the `form-data` is not proper to send file

Comment: I don't have the option of `multipart/form-data` in postman. The only available options are, `form-data`, `x-www-form-urlencoded`, `raw` and `binary`.

Comment: You can choose `form-data`, then go to the headers tab and modify `Content-Type` field to `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: No luck, same result. :(

Comment: Try requesting without any headers.

Comment: @Sagar, same result.

Comment: You ever figured this out? Have precisely same issue